# Inside linux kernel driver, how to get dma packet memory contents post mmap() into process coredump

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a process which does mmap into a kernel driver to map DMA packet memory into user space. When the process crashes want this memory to be part of coredump for post crash analysis.

Currently linux marks VM_IO flag for VMAs created as part of driver mmap function. In elf_core_dump() vma_dump_size() is called which checks for VM_IO flag and returns 0 if set. So these vmas are never added to coredump sections.

As per always_dump_vma() there seems probably a workaround to set vma->vm_ops 
having a name function pointer which should return non-NULL when invoked.

When extending this workaround to this driver mmap function running into second problem where the vma added is filled with zeroes by kernel elf_core_dump() instead of real data. In elf_core_dump() get_dump_page() for the DMA VMA pages returns NULL as the VMA has VM_IO flag. This results in dump_skip() instead of dump_emit() being called causing the problem.

How to workaround this second problem to get non-zero contents into process coredump for this packet memory vma ? Tried searching in various forums but did not get a precise solution.